# how to do sum in soql?

Tags: soql, aggregate

```
Double sumOfPrice = 0;
for(AggregateResult ar : [Select Id,Name, SUM(ProductPrice__c) totalUnitPrice from Inventory__c 
                                                        where OppLineItemId__c = :this.selectedOPLIId 
                                                        and OpportunityN__c = :this.opp.Id group by Name]){
            sumOfPrice = (Double) ar.get( 'totalUnitPrice' );
        }
```

I am getting following error:

> Field must be grouped or aggregated: Id

Comment: Please elaborate. What are you trying to accomplish, and how is your current code falling short of that goal?

Comment: I am just doing the sum of the field Product price from custom object inventory and add the value to a custom field on opportunitylineitem

Comment: @Sush If the below answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for just total value. you can remove grouping and do like below,

```
AggregateResult[] sumResult  = [Select SUM(ProductPrice__c)totalUnitPrice from Inventory__c 
                                                            where OppLineItemId__c = :this.selectedOPLIId 
                                                            and OpportunityN__c = :this.opp.Id];
sumOfPrice = (Double)groupedResults[0].get('totalUnitPrice');
```